# Why is the regularization term multiplied by the error term in the cost function of SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, regularization, loss-functions

The cost function of the Optimal Margin Classifier(non-kernelized SVM) is given as :
$$
J(\mathbf{\vec w}, b) = \frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{\vec w}\|_{2}^{2} + C \sum_{i=1}^{n}\max(0, 1-y ^{(i)}(\mathbf{\vec w}\cdot \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)} + b))
$$

> Why do we multiply the regularization parameter $C$ with the error term instead of the regularization term $\frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{\vec{w}}\|_2^2$ ?

The general form of a cost function is typically this :
$$
J_\lambda(\boldsymbol \theta) = J(\boldsymbol \theta) +  \lambda R(\boldsymbol \theta)
$$
where $R(\boldsymbol \theta)$ is the regularization term.
As you can see, the regularization parameter $\lambda$ is always multiplied by the regularization term. So why is the cost function of SVM so peculiar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're equivalent; just re-express $\lambda = \frac{1}{C}$ and multiply both sides by $\lambda$. Obviously, we assume $C > 0$.

$$J(\mathbf{\vec w}, b) = \frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{\vec w}\|_{2}^{2} + C \sum_{i=1}^{n}\max(0, 1-y ^{(i)}(\mathbf{\vec w}\cdot \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)} + b)) \\
\frac{1}{C} J(\mathbf{\vec w}, b) = \frac{1}{2C}\|\mathbf{\vec w}\|_{2}^{2} +  \sum_{i=1}^{n}\max(0, 1-y ^{(i)}(\mathbf{\vec w}\cdot \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)} + b))$$

Multiplying the cost function by a positive constant only changes the *value* of the cost but not the location of the minimum.